# Return list of values and match with type of product

Tags: microsoft-excel, search-indexing

I am looking for a formula which will create a report of expiring access of certain trainings.

Currently my table looks like:

| Name | Training1 | Training2 | Training3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 01/08/2023 | 01/08/2023 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | 01/08/2023 | 01/06/2023 | 01/10/2023 |
| Steve | 01/06/2023 | 01/06/2023 | 01/06/2023 |

I would like to create a mechanism which will show me training expiry within 45 day from now and expired, with list of names - modules and date when, something like:

Expiring within 45 days:

| Name | Module | Expiring on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training2 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training3 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |

Expired:

| Name | Module | Expiring on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training1 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training3 | 01/06/2023 |

I have managed to get formula to list names, but I cannot get how to match Training in header or date.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:D)/(B:D<TODAY()+45), ROW(1:1))),"") / expiring within 45 days
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:D)/(B:D<TODAY()), ROW(1:1))),"") / expired
```

How to rebuilt formula to match Training header and date for each person?

Comment: If you have Office 365, then the easiest mechanism for normalizing data, as you have it, would be to use Power Query to unpivot on the Training variables and add a custom column that calculates number of days until expiration. Then you could filter by `<=` number of days before loading to a sheet, or you could filter after loading (e.g., with a slicer).

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve this is using a `LET()` statement that allows you to store intermediate results. That way, you are able to bring your data in the correct form and filter then based on your conditions, e.g., date < today for the expired trainings.

I slightly extended your example to have a different number of names and modules to make the procedure more easily digestable. The data is stored in the range `A1:D5`:

| Name | Training1 | Training2 | Training3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 01/08/2023 | 01/08/2023 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | 01/08/2023 | 01/06/2023 | 01/10/2023 |
| Steve | 01/06/2023 | 01/06/2023 | 01/06/2023 |
| Bill | 01/06/2023 | 01/08/2023 | 01/10/2023 |

The `LET()` statement looks as follows:

```
=LET(
data,$A$1:$D$5,

nMod,COLUMNS(INDEX(data,1,))-1,
nRow,ROWS(INDEX(data,,1))-1,

tmpM,CHOOSEROWS(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(data,1,)),SEQUENCE(nMod,,2)),
modules,SORT(INDEX(tmpM,MOD(SEQUENCE(nMod*nRow)-1,nMod)+1)),

tmpN,CHOOSEROWS(INDEX(data,,1),SEQUENCE(nRow,,2)),
names,INDEX(tmpN,MOD(SEQUENCE(nMod*nRow)-1,nRow)+1),

dates,TOCOL(CHOOSEROWS(CHOOSECOLS(data,SEQUENCE(nMod,,2)),SEQUENCE(nRow,,2)),0,TRUE),

combinedTable, HSTACK(names,modules,dates),
filteredData,SORT(FILTER(combinedTable, INDEX(combinedTable,,3)<TODAY()),1),

result, VSTACK(HSTACK("Name", "Module", "Expiring on"), filteredData),
result)
```

You start by specifying the range of your data, e.g., `A1:D5` in this case. This could potentially be even further automated including a `COUNTA()` statement or similar, but given that the range needs to be specified only once, in most cases this is sufficent. Everything else is computed automatically.

Next, we start by computing the number of modules and rows, as the number of columns/rows in "data" - 1, given that the "Name" and "Header" is no relevant module or row. In the next step, we extract the respective names of modules (e.g., Training1-Training3) as `tmpM`. The modules need to be repeated for x times based on the number of relevant modules and rows. To achieve this, we combine `INDEX()` with `MOD()` and `SEQUENCE()`. The same procedure is repeated to create the respective name sequence that repeats the name as often as needed based on the modules. Lastly, we need to vertically stack all dates in one column rather than having it as a matrix. For this, we use mainly the `TOCOL()` function. In addition, we also select only the dates, i.e., no names and headers using additionally `CHOOSEROWS` and `CHOOSECOLS`. Once this is done, we horizontally stack together the "names", "modules", and "dates" using `HSTACK()`. The resulting table looks as follows:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |
| Steve | Training1 | 01/06/2023 |
| Bill | Training1 | 01/06/2023 |
| John | Training2 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Bill | Training2 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training3 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | Training3 | 01/10/2023 |
| Steve | Training3 | 01/06/2023 |
| Bill | Training3 | 01/10/2023 |

The next step is then a simple `FILTER()` statement that filters the data that has a date that is < `TODAY()`. For this, we want to filter the "combinedTable" based on the third column, i.e., the date. To use this information in the filter statement, we use the `INDEX()` function.

If you want to filter data that is within the next 45 days, you need to adjust the `FILTER()` statement as follows, such that you filter only thos cases that have a date > `TODAY()` and date <= `TODAY()+45`:

```
filteredData,SORT(FILTER(combinedTable,
(INDEX(combinedTable,,3)>TODAY())*(INDEX(combinedTable,,3)<=TODAY()+45)),1),
```

Once the data is filtered, we collect the results, i.e., include the relevant headers and use a `VSTACK()` statement to combine the headers with the filtered data. The output is a single spilling array that has all the relevant information and only needs one formula in a single cell. The final output looks as follows:

***Expired:***

| Name | Module | Expiring on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Training1 | 01/06/2023 |
| Mark | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training1 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training2 | 01/06/2023 |
| Steve | Training3 | 01/06/2023 |

***Expiring within 45 days:***

| Name | Module | Expiring on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Training2 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training2 | 01/08/2023 |
| John | Training3 | 01/08/2023 |
| Mark | Training1 | 01/08/2023 |

If you want to show intermediate steps, you can simply replace the last "result" in the formula with any other name that was defined, e.g., "combinedTable", "dates", etc.